# Invoking a synchronized method of the object while aquiring ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock on another thread

Tags: java, deadlock, static-methods, synchronized, reentrantreadwritelock

Thanks for considering my question, which I think is actually asking:

Not quite sure how exactly below code can deadlock.

The structure roughly looks like this, which has **2 classes** :

- The main class - **Worker** which has synchronized method
- A **util class** which has class level synchronized method

The `run` method of Worker will deadlock and making `doSomething()` not synchronized can avoid it.

The thread dump of the real application shows that :

the "Worker" thread is BLOCKED - waiting on monitor lock 
--> at int v = Utils.getIntValue();

the "schedule" thread is WAITING - [Thread State Details here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)
--> at (internal code of ReentrantReadWriteLock) after readWriteLock.readLock().lock();

```
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1009)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1324)
```

```java
public class Worker {

    ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public String getData() {

        try{
            readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
            return "Data";
        } finally {
            readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        // blocked due to the invocation of Utils.scheduleTask
        int v = Utils.getIntValue();
        System.out.println(v);
    }

    public void run() {
        // A static method which creates a thread that accesses the ReadWriteLock
        Utils.scheduleTask(this::getData);

        // some other quick tasks in between
        // ...

        // then enter this synchronized method
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Utils {

    static synchronized void scheduleTask(Runnable task) {

        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, r -> {
            Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
            t.setName("schedule");
            return t;
        });

        executorService.schedule(task, 0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    static int getIntValue() {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

I think it is due to the static synchronized method `scheduleTask` locking the whole `Utils` class and then before the thread from `ExecutorService` can aquire the `ReadLock` of the **`ReentrantReadWriteLock` inside Worker**, another method of Worker `doSomething()` locked on the Worker object (intrinsic lock) hence 2 threads are waiting on each other.

I could be wrong totally but if not wrong so far I am not sure how this instance of `ReentrantReadWriteLock` knows the Worker instance referencing it is locked by another thread ?

It seems that when the scheduled `Runnable task` is running the Utils class is still locked even after `scheduleTask` method has returned ?

---

**Updated** the `scheduleTask` to use 0 second delay to be closer to the actual scenario.

Thank you for your time considering this question !

Comment: You've got some crazy design there, but there doesn't seem to be any deadlock. You have 3 locks/monitors and 2 threads (presumably), which aren't sharing them.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for looking at the question, this is ofc a simplified version of an actual complex codebase evolved over time. Thread dump showed that the main thread - Worker - was in BLOCKED state i.e. waiting on monitor lock (The monitor of Utils class object perhaps ?) while "schedule" thread is on WAITING state and making "doSomething()" not synchronized made things moving forward. I am just trying to find out exactly why

Comment: Well look at the locks held by different threads and see which ones are competing for the locks. This isn't guesswork, this is science.

Answer (score 0):

It truns out there were another `synchronized` method of the "Worker" called from the `schedule` thread and there are methods from superclasses of "Worker" locked on the `ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock()` ...

"Worker" thread holds the `WriteLock` and waiting on monitor lock

"schedule" thread holds Worker object monitor lock and waiting on `ReadLock`